# How is a material heated by interband transitions?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrons, electronic-band-theory

If we excited the electrons in a material via interband transitions, how do we go from these to the material heating up? Is it due to relaxation of the electronic states back to their ground state? Perhaps it induces electron phonon scattering within the material?

Answer (score 1):

If the material absorbs a photon of just the bandgap energy (an interband transition), and then if that photon re-radiates a photon to relax to the ground state, then there is no heating. But usually, the photon has a bit more energy than the bandgap and is excited with excess energy. The first thing that happens is the excited electron relaxes to the band edge. This often happens through phonon emission, which is heat.

So to summarize, the heat comes from the excess energy the photon has over the bandgap.